# SSRS Report builder with multiple IIf expressions, how to read the code

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have an old report with a column that has an expression looking like this:

`=IIf(Sum(Fields!projqty.Value)<>0, IIf(Max(Fields!projekttargettime.Value)=1, 
(Sum(Fields!projtime.Value+Fields!acwtime.Value)), 
(Sum(Fields!projqty.Value)*Fields!targettime.Value)), 
(Sum(Fields!projqty.Value)*Fields!targettime.Value))`

I dont understand how to read the code and wonder if someone could explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called an inline if, or `iif()`.

An inline if basically goes along the lines of:
`iif(<test condition>, <value for true>, <value for false>)`

For your example, you also have nested `iif()` statements to work things out. 
It goes..

`IIf(Sum(Fields!projqty.Value)<>0` - check to see if this `sum(Fields!projqty.Value)` is not equal to 0

`IIf(Max(Fields!projekttargettime.Value)=1` - the first test was true (not equal to 0), so now we want to check if this `max(Fields!projekttargettime.Value)` is equal to 1

`(Sum(Fields!projtime.Value+Fields!acwtime.Value)),` - we got here because the `sum(Fields!projqty.Value)` is not equal to 0 and the `max(Fields!projekttargettime.Value)` is equal to 1

`(Sum(Fields!projqty.Value)*Fields!targettime.Value)),` - we got here because the `sum(Fields!projqty.Value)` is not equal to 0 and the `max(Fields!projekttargettime.Value)` does not equal 1

`(Sum(Fields!projqty.Value)*Fields!targettime.Value))` - and finally, we got here because the original `sum(Fields!projqty.Value)` is equal to 0. We never check for `max(Fields!projekttargettime.Value)` as we don't reach that part of the `iif()`

See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-examples-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017) for more information on expressions in SSRS.

Comment: Just a small correction, `IIf(Sum(Fields!projqty.Value)<>0` checks if the Sum of the `projqty` values are NOT EQUAL to 0, not necessarily greater than 0.